# Need suggection on html CSS javascript hover & slide

Tags: jquery, css, html

I need a little suggestion, this is my [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/M7Km2/), and my HTML:

```
<div style="width: 100%; border: 1px solid #000000;">
        <div style="float: left; width: 20%;">Logo + <a href="#">Sub nav icon</a></div>
        <div style="float: left; width: 60%;">Canter HEader portion</div>
        <div style="float: left; width: 20%;">Right postion</div>
        <br clear=all>
  </div>
<div style="width: 100%;  border: 1px solid #000000; margin-top: 10px;">
    <div style="float: left; width: 20%">Sub menu Hidden</div>
    <div style="float: left; width: 80%">
        <div style="float: left; width: 60%">Image area</div>
        <div style="float: left; width: 40%">Text Area</div>
        <br clear=all>
    </div>
    <br clear=all>
</div>
```

<sub>(Note that this was copied and pasted in an edit *not* by the OP, the code has not been edited for correctness.)</sub>

What I need is that when I click on 'Sub Nav Icon Link' the Sub Menu Hidden from the second div should open in slide down method, and should shift the 80% width container to right & adjust the available width accordingly. Then, when I click on 'close' link the sub menu should close by sliding up and the 80% width would take the 100% width.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You could try [jQuery Menus](https://jqueryui.com/menu/). It will do your work for you.

Comment: I cant use that want i want what the menu is open then i want the divs width to be 80% & when i close the menu the width should be 100%

Answer (score 0):

As per your code you need to write some jquery using `animate` to show/ hide your submenu **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/M7Km2/1/)**

```
$('.open').click(function(){
    $(this).hide();
    $('.close').show();
    $('.content').animate({ marginLeft: '20%' });
    $('.sMenu').animate({ marginLeft: '0' });
});
$('.close').click(function(){
    $(this).hide();
    $('.open').show();
    $('.content').animate({ marginLeft: '0' });
    $('.sMenu').animate({ marginLeft: '-20%' });
});
```